# Can you earn the Hero Of Time hat for the Winter Bash past 7:00PM

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2017

Can you earn the Hero of Time hat for the Winter Bash past 7:00PM (such as 9:42PM or 11:36PM)?

Comment: If it was 7:00 PM at any time zone in the world, you earn it.

Comment: @gparyani, you mean it has to be exactly 7:00PM sharp?

Comment: Why? Posting at x:00 pretty much get's it for you, no matter what time it actually is for you

Comment: Ah. I understand. So it could be any time. Understood. I thought it meant it had to be your time zone, at 7:00PM-11:59PM. Thanks!

Comment: The questions has to be posted at 7:00pm **anywhere** in the world. (so as long as you post it *on the hour*, you're good)

Comment: kinda curious to what the slop there is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should post a question when it is 7 PM anywhere in the world. The description reads:

> Ask a question when it is **7:00 pm in any time zone**.

So it does not need to be your timezone. It is implicit that the question should be upvoted.

Comment: Confirmed that. Posted at 1200hrs SGT, 7 PM ... somewhere else